# Си. Структуры. Вылезают лишние байты

Tags: c, указатели, struct, segmentation-fault

Как с помощью gdb найти на какой строке произошел segfault?

Выделяю массив структур через malloc на указатель. Этот массив заполняю тыщей элеметов. Когда набирается этот массив полностью  вызываю метод, который работает так. Создаю `void` указатель `pbuffer`, на нем `malloc(146*count+19+2)`. 19 и 2 это голова и хвост протокола.

Создаю указатель `void p` на `pbuffer+19` и двигаю его в цикле +146 и записываю новую структуру на ходу. Дальше отправляю в сеть и `free(pbuffer)`. Вот при нескольких элементах получается все хорошо, а при тыщенке - сегфолт.

Как отладить такие ситуации?

Comment: Для начала посмотрите, чему равен `sizeof(ваша структура)` (скорее всего ее поля требуют выравнивания и компилятор добавляет "лишние" байты (это называется padding))

Comment: Во-первых, тут никому не интересен ваш живописный рассказ о том, какой у вас там код. Приводите сам код, а не художественные рассказы про него. Во-вторых, что значит "как с помощью gdb найти на какой строке произошел segfault"? Запустите gdb и он сам вам все покажет.

Comment: а может valgrind поможет, если это линукс. или -fsanitizer=address, если это свежий gcc/clang

Comment: Очень странно двигать указатель (void*), а писать структуру. У вас так совпало, что sizeof(void) == sizeof(struct)? Посмотрите внимательно главу по работе с указателями, конкретно вам нужен сдвиг указателей и выделение памяти через malloc()

Comment: @AnT "минимальный код" заработает как надо - я уверен на 80%, а на полный код скажите "нам не интересен этот запутанный кусок говна - перепешите" вопрос то в другом.

Comment: @avp - padding убрал уже.

Comment: @wirtwelt void двигается по "большой" области 146*count+19+2. а структура записывается в нужные места через указатель на структуру

Comment: Вы не поняли. Компилятор всегда знает, какой тип (размер) имеет указатель по размеру данных, на которые он указывает. Если вы "сдвигаете" указатель на type на +1, то он сдвинет численно указатель на `+1*sizeof(type)` байт. Поэтому если вы берете байтовый массив, выделенный malloc(1000), и думаете что там 1000 ваших структур, это не так, если `sizeof(struct) != sizeof(char)`. Там просто 1000 байт. Я как раз об этом. Вам нужно выделять не байтами, а `malloc(sizeof(struct) * N)`, чтобы получить область памяти под N структур.

Comment: Пример: пусть структура у вас из двух `int` и называется допустим `point`. Вы выделяете через `malloc(1000)`. Потом берете указатель `point *p = malloc(1000);`. Указатель `p`  указывает на тип с размером `sizeof(point)`, пусть на нашей архитектуре это 4+4=8. При сдвиге на `p = p + 124;` вы сдвините указатель реально на 124*8= 992 байта от начала области, а не на 124, как ожидаете. А при сдвиге `p = p + 125` вы получите выход за границу выделенной памяти и SIGFAULT. Тут не нужен gdb.

Comment: @eri: Тем на менее пытаться "угадывать" ошибку по словесному описанию, которое не имеет практически никакого отношения к коду (вы нам рассказываете, что хотели реализовать, а не что фактически реализовали) - занятие бесполезное. Код нужен, а уж целиком или выборочно - вопрос отдельный.

Comment: @wirtwelt интересная идея, но sizeof(void*) = 1, так что двигаюсь ровненько

Comment: @AnT, не надо угадывать ошибку - я спрашивал как отладить, а не как исправить

Comment: @eri: "sizeof(void*) = 1"? Это что за белиберда?

Comment: @eri, запустите свою программу под gdb, пройдите по шагам, записывая изменения значений переменных, почертите карандашом, как движутся данные по памяти в соответствии с циклами и **обдумайте, что реально видите**. Тут вы ошибочку и поймаете.

Comment: да по шагам сложно в том моменте, что на 10 объектах все работет как часы и каждый байтик на месте. падаем значениях ближе к тыщи. если бы это была простая ошибка - она бы накапливалась

Comment: @eri, есть такая чукотская пословица -- *скорее безногий станет охотником, чем нетерпеливый*. imho с некоторыми очевидными изменениями она применима и тут. Короче, хотите найти ошибку, беретесь за клавиатуру и действуете, заочно (и без кода) никто за вас ее не найдет

Comment: @avp первая задача научиться самому найти косяк, а не то что чтоб кто-то нашел его за меня. Пример кода будет завтра. Нашел интересную штуку. у меня тут указатель двинуло на пару десятков тысяч хотя в цикле +2 +144 (453 раза)

Comment: свою задачку я решил...

Comment: @Abyx я люблю изучать что-то сложное. потом простое будет проще

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего у вас выход за выделенную область памяти

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/

Если вы выделяете `malloc(146*count+19+2)`, то можно предположить, что 19 - это фиксированный заголовок вашего пакета, 2 это контрольная сумма, а 146 - это размер одного блока данных, которых может быть count штук

Отсюда вопрос: почему вы используете указатель `void*` вместо `char*`, если хотите двигать его побайтно? Вы уверены, что в вашей среде `sizeof(void) == sizeof(char)`?

Используйте `char *p = (char*)pbuffer`, и тогда:

```
char *pbuffer = malloc(19 + 146*count + 2);
char *packet = NULL;
for (i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    packet = p
     + 19 // Сдвигаемся на 19 sizeof(char)
     + i * 146; // Сдвигаемся на i блоков, которые уже записали
    // packet всегда будет указывать на блок данных правильно
    ...
}
...
// Не забудьте сделать free после того, как обработаете все данные из области
free(pbuffer);
```

Еще раз повторю то, что написал в комментарии: сдвиг указателя на тип `type` на +N это сдвиг на `sizeof(type) * N`, а не на N байт

Comment: В С не поддерживается адресная арифметика с `void *` указателями, поэтому ее все равно придется делать через конверсию в `char *`. Нестандартные компиляторы С-подобных языков, поддерживающие такую арифметику, трактуют `void *` как `char *` (именно для целей адресной арифметики), т.е. двигается такой указатель тоже побайтно. `sizeof(void)` в С нет вообще.

Comment: gcc (GCC) 7.2.0 - sizeof(void)==1.
переставлю на char. всякий случай, но вопрос был "как отладить", а не как исправить

Comment: @eri: Это не С. В компиляторе GCC поддержка языка С начинается с указания флагов `-std=...` и `-pedantic`. Без этого комипилируемый GCC язык - это некий С-подобный суррогат. И еще раз: в языке С нет адресной арифметики для типа `void *` и в языке С запрещается применять `sizeof` к типу `void`.

Comment: @eri,самый простой и быстрый метод отладки - printf. Используем повсеместно. Если есть какой-то плохой или ломающийся кусок кода, он покрывается `printf("%s:%u", __FILE__, __LINE__);` и отлаживается, после чего отладка удаляется. Пробовали gdb, но из-за кросскомпиляции и увеличения размеров бинарника от него отказались. Ваш случай кажется не очень сложным, я бы посоветовал выводить в цикле указатель старта области, указатель который сдвигается (`%p` для адресов) и посмотреть, что происходит. Возможно SIGSEGV не там, где вы думаете, такое часто бывает на практике.

Comment: @eri, еще один вариант отладки из практической части - комментирование через `#ifdef 0` или обычный комментарий `/* ... */`. Это уровень детского сада конечно, но с его помощью вполне успешно решаются насущные проблемы опечаток, не тех переменных или подобных мелких ошибок. Советы так себе конечно ) Просто описываю, чем пользуемся я и мои коллеги в работе

Answer (score 4):

> Как с помощью gdb найти на какой строке произошел segfault?

1. Скомпилируйте программу с флагом отладочной информации
2. Запустите программу из под gdb
3. Когда она упадёт, дайте команду 'bt'

Будет распечатан стек вызовов функций с указанием номеров строк.

Comment: бактрейс показывает только функцию на которой остановился. именно строку я там не видел

Comment: скомпилировать нужно именно с отладочной информацией. для gcc/clang это флажок -ggdb

Comment: номера строчек появились